Telegram API forwardMessage wtih reply_to(message) or caption
I'm trying to forward message with forwardMessage and it works fine, but when someone replies to the message it only forwards the reply, not the original message. Am I missing something? Is there some way to forward the original message too?
def forwardMessage(message):
    method = "forwardMessage"
    url = f"https://api.telegram.org/bot{token}/{method}"
    for chat in chat_ids:
        if chat != str(message["message"]["chat"]["id"]):
            data = {"from_chat_id":message["message"]"chat"]"id"],"message_id": message["message"]["message_id"],"chat_id": chat}
            respons = requests.post(url, data=data)

I need to forward the message with the original message.
